# No route matches [GET] "/place/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I can't catch where a problem is.

I run on server

```
rails generate scaffold Place name:string lat:numeric lng:numeric
```

Next, I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

So, I try to create new Place on web browser and go to

```
/places/new
```

But receive:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/place/new"):
```

I confused because everything works fine on my local machine. What's wrong with me?

btw, routes.rb looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
    resources :places
end
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` returns you?

Comment: You can always check what routes are generated by running `rake routes`

Comment: How are you navigating to `/places/new`? with a link? please post the code

Comment: what do mean *everything works fine on my local machine*?

Answer (score 1):

You're saying you're navigating to `places/new`, but the log entry you've included shows that you're actually trying to navigate to `place/new`, which is not a valid route in this case. Use the plural for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

`numeric` is not a datatype. You have to use `float` or `integer` for lat/long instead of `numeric`.

Corrected command:

```
rails generate scaffold Place name:string lat:integer lng:integer
```

Comment: Thats the mistake. But this not the solution to the problem!

Comment: @Pavan Its the first problem..if first is fixed then it might be possible that all other solutions be fixed.

Comment: That is not the problem for the issue which he is getting currently.

Comment: While not listed in the generators, numeric seems to work just fine as a type and is listed in [add_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column)....just ran `rails generate scaffold Place name:string lat:numeric lng:numeric` locally and everything seems to be working just fine with it in the console

Comment: I tried the same and it getting error `undefined method `numeric' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters`

Comment: Looks like it's [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb) in the 5.0 branches but is absent [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb) in the 4.2 stable branch, so must be a rails 5 feature; they haven't specified which version of rails they're on, but since they pasted that a command ran with numeric, I'm going to assume they're on rails 5

Comment: I am using rails 4.1.7 with pg database